# How can I present a modal view controller after selecting a contact?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, model-view-controller

I'm trying to present a modal view controller after selecting a contact and it doesnt seem to be working.

In my -

```
(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
```

method, I dismiss peoplePicker, create an instance of my new view controller, then present it with

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

and it doesnt work. However if i PUSH the view controller it works with this code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the presentModalViewController on your own controller instead of the navigation controller.
If you're in the context of a UIViewController:
[self presentModalViewController:newController animated:YES];

Comment: Thanks it works, but the animation looks kind of funny. Like the new view and all its elements are not all at the front or something. Any ideas why?